# How to write a method that returns strings that contain every object from an array

Tags: java, methods

I want to write a method that has an array (not arrayList) as a parameter. That method should check if multiple strings contain all the words stated in the array, and therefore returns strings that do. Is there a way of doing it just by using for loops and string methods?

I tried to do something like this:

```
public String text (String[] words) {
    String concatedStrings = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < numStrings.length; i++) {
        if(numStrings[i] != null) {
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if(numStrings[i].contains(words[j])) {
                    concatedStrings += numStrings[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return concatedStrings;
}
```

Comment: keep a boolean -> while (String s : mustBeIn ) if ( !originalString.contains(s)) flag = false;

Comment: break out of the loop if you encounter false, and you'll have your answer

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem with your code? My guess is that strings that happen to include multiple strings from `words` are concatenated multiple times? In that case you need a strategically-placed `break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct but needs some modification on your code.

```
public String text(String[] words, String[] strings) {
    String concatedStrings = "";
    for (String s : strings) { // loop through all the strings
        boolean containsAllWords = true;
        for (String word : words) { // check if the current string contains all the words
            if (!s.contains(word)) {
                containsAllWords = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (containsAllWords) {
            concatedStrings += s;
        }
    }
    return concatedStrings;
}
```

in main method:

```
String[] words = {"hello", "world"};
String[] strings= {"hello world", "world hello", "hello there"};
```